# Why is the SurfaceView cut if I resume app?

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, resume

If I use an Android L device and resume my app, the SurfaceViews are cut.

The details of occurrence condition are as follows:
- Using Android L (It is originally L, not updated to L)
- The SurfaceView is larger than the display.
- The left-top of SurfaceView is more to the left or top of the display.
- Resuming the app from the background apps list, not the icon in the app list.

I tried to reset size, gravity, clip bounds, etc., however, none had effect.
I want to repair the SurfaceView cut, you do not have some idea?

The sample code is as follows:

[Activity]

```
public class ViewTestActivity extends Activity {

    private DrawSurfaceView mDrawSurfaceView;
    private int overDispW;
    private int overDispH;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point dispP = new Point();
        display.getSize(dispP);
        overDispW = (int) (dispP.x * 1.5);
        overDispH = (int) (dispP.y * 1.5);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams overSizeParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(overDispW, overDispH);

        //If gravity is Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.TOP, there is no cut.
        overSizeParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

        mDrawSurfaceView = new DrawSurfaceView(this);

        setContentView(mDrawSurfaceView, overSizeParams);
    }
}
```

[SurfaceView]

```
public class DrawSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private Paint mPaintRed;
    private Paint mPaintBlue;
    private Paint mPaintGreen;
    private Paint mPaintYellow;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;

    public DrawSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mPaintRed = new Paint();
        mPaintRed.setColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0));

        mPaintBlue = new Paint();
        mPaintBlue.setColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 255));

        mPaintGreen = new Paint();
        mPaintGreen.setColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 255, 0));

        mPaintYellow = new Paint();
        mPaintYellow.setColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 0));

        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        drawRect(canvas);
    }

    private void drawRect(Canvas canvas) {
        int w = canvas.getWidth();
        int h = canvas.getHeight();
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, Mode.CLEAR);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, w/2, h/2, mPaintRed);
        canvas.drawRect(w/2, h/2, w, h, mPaintBlue);
        canvas.drawRect(w/2, 0, w, h/2, mPaintGreen);
        canvas.drawRect(0, h/2, w/2, h, mPaintYellow);
    }

    public void doDraw(){
        Canvas canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas();
        if(canvas != null){
            drawRect(canvas);
            mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        doDraw();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        doDraw();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right side of view has been cut.

[image]